# Why doesn't a regex pattern qualify as a javascript data type?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var rclass = /[\n\t\r]/g;
```

In the above, there are no `""`, or `''` around it, so it cannot be a string, is this not its own data type? Why then does it not qualify?

Also, why do we not put `""`, `''` around it and just represent it as a string?

Comment: It is a shorthand for `new RegExp("[\n\t\r]", "g");`, it has its own constructor.

Comment: Wow!! Ok thanks, gee wiz, go the interpreter huh!

Comment: The special quoting for regex is there so that you don't have to do double/quadruple escapes like in some other languages (*cough* PHP *cough* Java *cough*). `/\s\\\s/` if quoted with `""` would have to be written like `"\\s\\\\\\s"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript you can create most *things* in two ways.

Either by calling its constructor function:

```
var myConstructedString = new String( "foo" );
var myConstructedRegExp = new RegExp("[\n\t\r]", "g");
```

Or using [literals](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8):

```
var myLiteralString = "bar";
var myLiteralRegExp = /[\n\t\r]/g;
```

[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is no exception. [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is one type (Date actually not being a type but a sub type of the Object type) that has no literal notation.

So to answer one of your questions, "is this not its own data type?". No it´s not, RegExp is of type Object, just like Date and Math. There are only six [types](http://es5.github.io/#x8) in JavaScript

A good read is [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals) at MDN.

Comment: Remember that there is a slight difference between `new String` and a string literal, since using `typeof` on the former returns `object`, while on the latter returns `string`.

Comment: Exactly! This is one of those nuances in JavaScript that many stumble upon. That's why you use `Object.prototype.toString.call`.

Answer (score 3):

when you have:

```
var myRegex = /myRegex/;
```

`typeof myRegex` returns "object" and not "string".
This means that `/myRegex/` is actualy not a string but a real object with its own methods (I can see on it an "exec" function for example, or "ignoreCase"...).

I also found the Object RegExp: `new RegExp("myRegex")` returns .... `/myregex/` :-)

It turns out that the way of creating a regex with `/myRegex/` syntax is a syntax convention equivalent to `new RegExp("myRegex")`.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how you define a regular expression in JS. A regular expression is delimited by the `/` characters. Remember, that a regular expression is *not* a string, it is something in its own right. [This is a nice article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) on the matter.